# run php from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a countdown timer when it finish it run a php script (file called ajax.php) the problem is the ajax.php run many times .

i want to get this result in the table

```
[id][content]
[1][timer]
```

---

but i get this result

```
[id][content]
[1][timer]
[2][timer]
[3][timer]
[4][timer]
[5][timer]
[6][timer]
[7][timer]
[8][timer]
[9][timer]
.....
```

this is the code

```
    <div id="counter"></div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    var div = $('#counter');

    var n = 5000;

    var blured = false;

    var tid = setInterval(function() {
        if (blured) return;    
        n -= 100;
        div.text( (n / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' seconds passed' );
        if ( n <= 0 ) {


        div.text('Time passed!'); 
        $.ajax({

        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data, status) {}

        });




        }


    }, 100);

    window.onblur = function() {
        blured = true;    
    };

    window.onfocus = function() {
        blured = false;    
    };


        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
        // document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
        window.onblur = function() {
            blured = true;    
        };
        window.onfocus = function() {
            blured = false;    
        };


    </script>
```

and this is ajax.php

```
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw") or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die ("Coouldn't Select Database");


    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record VALUES ('', 'timer')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var tid = setInterval(function() {
    if (blured) return;    
    n -= 100;
    div.text( (n / 1000).toFixed(1) + ' seconds passed' );
    if ( n <= 0 ) {


    div.text('Time passed!'); 
  clearTimeout(tid);
    $.ajax({

    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data, status) {}

    });




    }


}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually how **setInterval** works. From your code I can see that you are setting it to 100 milliseconds, therefore your browser will make the ajax call once every 0.1 second and it will go on forever.
In order to avoid it you must first know that the function setInterval() returns an ID that you can use to later clear that event handler. Simply use **clearInterval()**.

Example:

```
var tid = setInterval(function(){},100);

/*Later you can use*/
clearInterval(tid);
```

If you need more information checkout the documentation for [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) and [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval).